# Bring php page into java code

Tags: java, php

I have a webpage i.e. php page and its a form. I want to bring this page into java i.e. in java page i want to display this form using the URL of the .php page. Is it possible and if so how ?

Clarification in question:

I have a java webpage. In this webpage i want a Iframe or anything of that sort which will display a php form in it using a php url and perform save action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand your question. I assume you want a jsp page (what you call a Java page), who just display the content of your php page. If this is the case, then you need a redirect:

```
<%
    String redirectURL = "http://www.exmple.com/your_page.php";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

Comment: please see the question for clarification.

Comment: @Hacker: if your "java webpage" is a jsp, then I guess you just need to add `<iframe src="http://www.exmple.com/your_page.php"></iframe> `

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a Swing application, you can embed a browser using the DJ project: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/, which you can manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want Java to grab info from a web page? I.e Screen Scraping....

See this: [Web scraping, screen scraping, data mining tips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079784/web-scraping-screen-scraping-data-mining-tips)

Comment: @Brian- please see the question for clarification.